# Como contar cuantos cuartos de hora hay (15 min) en un intervalo de tiempo entre hora de inicio y hora fin? en C# winforms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, oledb

```
private void txtTeeTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime inicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpInicio.Text);
    DateTime fin = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFin.Text);
    TimeSpan duracion = fin - incio;

    DateTime teetime = DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(dauer.Hours);
    txtTeeTime.Text = (teetime.Hour).ToString();  
}
```

Comment: `var cuartosDeHora = duracion.TotalMinutes /15;`?

Comment: No se como usar var en este codigo

Comment: Var simplemente es que no especificas el tipo,pero puedes usar double si quieres.

Comment: DateTime inicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpInicio.Text);
            DateTime final = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFinal.Text);
            TimeSpan dracion = final - inicio;
            double teetime = dauer.TotalMinutes / 15;

            txtTeeTime.Text = teetime.ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solicionado asi:

private void txtTeeTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime inicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpInicio.Text);
            DateTime final = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFinal.Text);
            TimeSpan duracion = final - inicio;
            double final = Convert.ToDouble(duracion.TotalMinutes / 15);
            txtTeeTime.Text = final.ToString();